# Custom Login Form Bean in Spring Security Failurehandler

Tags: spring, spring-security

Version: Spring Security 4.2.3

I need some additional values like 'Form Action' from the login Jsp page. 
Is it possible to fetch the form bean "logonForm" in the custom SuccessHandler or FailureHandler. I attempted Autowired and this did not help. Any suggestions?

**Custom Login JSP**

```
 <form:form action="userLogon" commandName="logonForm" >  
 <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action"/>
```

**FailureHandler**

```
public class MyAppAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler  {
private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
@Autowired(required=false)
@Qualifier("logonForm")
private LogonForm logonForm;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    setUseForward(true); // ensure it is a server forward than client redirect

    if (authException != null) {
        String userId = logonForm.getUserId();
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be simpler, the login field values were available from the API:

```
String userId = request.getParameter("userId");
String action= request.getParameter("action");
```